# My rvest code does not scrape the text from the web

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, rvest

I'd like to scrape the web page like this: https://azreportcards.azed.gov/schools/detail/79645
I tried to extract text called "Mission Statement" here on this webpage.
My intention was that I would scrape all the Mission Statements in each school information page building up a huge repository of these.

I can search where it is in the HTML console, but after multiple tries of web scraping I could not scrape this text from the webpage. 
Please read my code here.

`urls<-"https://azreportcards.azed.gov/schools/detail/79645"
html <- read_html(urls)
cast <- html_nodes(html, ".//*[@id="school info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[7]/div[3]/text()")
length(cast)`

But this one didn't scrape any text from this webpage.
I tried other things like SelectorGadget and Selenium but failed.
Do you know the reason for this problem?